# Finding the range and averaging the corresponding elements in R

Tags: r, range, average

I have different range of numbers (or coordinates) in one dataset and i want to find suitable range of numbers and then take average of corresponding scores.

Lets say my dataset is:

```
coordinate score    
     1000   1.1
     1001   1.2
     1002   1.1
     1003   1.4
     1006   1.8
     1007   1.9
     1010   0.5
     1011   1.1
     1012   1.0
```

I should find the proper boundary (when `coordinate` is not consecutive) and then calculate mean for each particular range.

my desired result:

```
start end mean-score
1000 1003  1.2
1006 1007  1.85
1010 1012  0.86
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (assuming `df` is your data set)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, indx := .GRP, by = list(cumsum(c(1, diff(coordinate)) - 1))]
df[, list(start = coordinate[1],
          end = coordinate[.N],
          mean_score = round(mean(score), 2)), by = indx]

#    indx start  end mean_score
# 1:    1  1000 1003       1.20
# 2:    2  1006 1007       1.85
# 3:    3  1010 1012       0.87
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(indx = dense_rank(cumsum(c(1, diff(coordinate)) - 1))) %>%
  group_by(indx) %>%
  summarise(start = first(coordinate),
            end = last(coordinate),
            mean_score = round(mean(score), 2))

# Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
# 
#   indx start  end mean_score
# 1    1  1000 1003       1.20
# 2    2  1006 1007       1.85
# 3    3  1010 1012       0.87
```

---

Here are some alternative base R solutions (much less efficient)

```
df$indx <- as.numeric(factor(cumsum(c(1, diff(df$coordinate)) - 1)))
cbind(aggregate(coordinate ~ indx, df, function(x) c(start = head(x, 1), end = tail(x, 1))),
      aggregate(score ~ indx, df, function(x) mean_score = round(mean(x), 2)))

#   indx coordinate.start coordinate.end indx score
# 1    1             1000           1003    1  1.20
# 2    2             1006           1007    2  1.85
# 3    3             1010           1012    3  0.87
```

Or

```
cbind(do.call(rbind, (with(df, tapply(coordinate, indx, function(x) c(start = head(x, 1), end = tail(x, 1)))))),
with(df, tapply(score, indx, function(x) mean_score = round(mean(x), 2))))

#   start  end     
# 1  1000 1003 1.20
# 2  1006 1007 1.85
# 3  1010 1012 0.87
```

Comment: creating `indx` is a brilliant idea. could you explain the part `setDT(df)[, indx := .GRP, by = list(cumsum(c(1, diff(coordinate)) - 1))]` ? thanks

Comment: `diff` calculates the differences between consecutive values. I'm doing `-1` so the values that only have a difference of 1 will have a values of 0. Thus when doing `cumsum` it counts them in the same group as `0 + 0 + 0 = 0`. The moment the distance is bigger than 1, cumsum will add a new value and then keep adding zeroes so it will be a new group and so on. For `.GRP` see `?data.table`. You can actually do this with base R too but much less efficiently, I''ll add the base R solution as soon I'll have a chancce

Comment: See my edit for base R and `dplyr`. `dplyr` should be very efficient too